# how to add orginal price on order email template

Tags: magento-1.9, email-templates

```
<?php
if ($this->helper('tax')->displaySalesPriceInclTax($_order->getStore())) {
$itemprice = $this->helper('checkout')->getPriceInclTax($_item) ;
echo $this->helper('checkout')->formatPrice($itemprice);
} else {
echo $this->helper('checkout')->formatPrice($_item->getPrice()) ;
}
```

with help of above code i am able to add unit special price but i want to add original price. anyone can help me

Comment: i want to add original price in order email template while i am adding unit price but its special price.

Answer (score 1):

you can get the original price by

```
echo $this->helper('checkout')->formatPrice($_item->getOriginalPrice()) ;
```

or

```
echo $this->helper('checkout')->formatPrice($_item->getBaseOriginalPrice()) ;
```

or you can get product price

```
echo $this->helper('checkout')->formatPrice($_item->getProdcut()->getPrice()) ;
```

Comment: ....its not working for me it is still showing special price but i want to show original price ...e.g if i have one product original price is 90 and special price is 60 than i want to show 90 on email order

Comment: did you tried the last one what is output of that?

Comment: same it is showing special price not original price

Comment: please help me if possible ....

Comment: then go for `$itemproduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_item->getProductId());
echo $itemproduct->getPrice();` this is tested code

Comment: i wrote as like this it is right or wrong ......<?php

$itemproduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_item->getProductId‌​()); echo $itemproduct->getPrice();
?>

Comment: <?php $itemproduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_item->getProductId‌​‌​()); 
echo $this->helper('checkout')->formatPrice($itemproduct->getPrice()) ; ?> write like that

Comment: when i am using this code after click on place order it does not show success or failure message but in backend order is placing

Comment: check the error log for errors what error generating ?

Comment: make sure you are editing correct file `base/default/email/order/items/order/default.phtml`

Comment: i checked error log ......nothing

Comment: yes i am editing correct file ...

Comment: did you enable the error log from admin panel?

Comment: yes i have enabled

Comment: can you add your latest code so i can check where is problem?

Comment: i am adding this code  <?php $itemproduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_item->getProductId‌​‌​‌​()); echo $this->helper('checkout')->formatPrice($itemproduct->getPric‌​e()) ; ?>

Comment: can you check my code and update me. i am waiting your response

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '??' (T_COALESCE) in C:\xampp\htdocs\giftingideas\app\design\frontend\base\default\template\email\order\items\order\default.phtml on line 52

Comment: line 52 paste here

Comment: its line no 52 $itemproduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_item->getProductId‌​‌​‌​‌​());

Comment: add the complete code you are added `??>` in that line too kindly check that and remove the `?`

Comment: now i have fixed my error but order email template is totally blank there is nothing.

Comment: try this code `$itemproduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_item->getProductId‌​()); echo $itemproduct->getPrice()`

Comment: okay let me check....

Comment: now i am using this <?php
 $itemproduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_item->getProductId‌​‌​()); ?>
 <?php echo $itemproduct->getPrice();?> but i am getting error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '??' (T_COALESCE) in C:\xampp\htdocs\shopping\app\design\frontend\base\default\template\email\order\items\order\default.phtml on line 62

Comment: check the line 62 for that error where is '??' in php code

Answer (score 1):

you can do this steps this always works for me

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_item->getProductId‌​());
echo $product->getPrice();
```

Comment: i am asking about order email template...

Comment: just place this code in php $item loop instead your code , I have used `$_item`  varibale and load orignal product and fetch its actual price

Comment: okay lets me check ...

Comment: <?php
if ($this->helper('tax')->displaySalesPriceInclTax($_order->getStore())) {
$itemprice = $this->helper('checkout')->getPriceInclTax($_item) ;
echo $this->helper('checkout')->formatPrice($itemprice);
} else {
echo $this->helper('checkout')->formatPrice($_item->getPrice()) ;
}

Comment: <?php
if ($this->helper('tax')->displaySalesPriceInclTax($_order->getStore())) {
$itemprice = $this->helper('checkout')->getPriceInclTax($_item) ;
echo $this->helper('checkout')->formatPrice($itemprice);
} else {
echo $this->helper('checkout')->formatPrice($_item->getPrice()) ;
} where should i paste your code

Comment: @MurtuzaZabuawala this will return `$_item->getId()` item id not the product id for product id use `$_item->getProductId‌​()`

Comment: i update my code with <?php

$itemproduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_item->getProductId‌​()); echo $itemproduct->getPrice();
?> but its not working

Comment: first echo  this code `$_item->getProductId‌​‌​()` have you got the product id

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '??' (T_COALESCE) in C:\xampp\htdocs\giftingideas\app\design\frontend\base\default\template\email\order\items\order\default.phtml on line 52

Comment: have you miss semicolon or something please check

Comment: now i have fixed my error i used this code <?php   $itemproduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_item->getProductId‌​($_item));  ?>
 <?php echo $product->getPrice(); ?> but now order email is totally blank

Comment: I think There may be another 500 error debug that